# Grouping the details of the data into one, price field should be separated by semi-colon

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this requirement that need to group the data into OrderNum, the price needs to be consolidated in one row separated by semi-colon, this was determined by Type. I can do this by Iterating the results but, probably there's a better way to do it especially in LINQ.

```
var notebooks = new List<NoteBook>
            {
                new NoteBook { Type = 1, Currency = "USD", Price = 1000, OrderNum = "123" },
                new NoteBook { Type = 2, Currency = "USD", Price = 2000, OrderNum = "123" },
                new NoteBook { Type = 0, Currency = "USD", Price = 3000, OrderNum = "456" },
                new NoteBook { Type = 0, Currency = "USD", Price = 4000, OrderNum = "789" },
                new NoteBook { Type = 4, Currency = "USD", Price = 5000, OrderNum = "753" }

            };

            var results = from r in notebooks
                          group r by new { r.OrderNum } into g
                          select new
                              {
                                  Currency = g.First().Currency,
                                  OrderNum = g.First().OrderNum,
                                  Price = ???
                              };
```

I'm expecting a result of

```
Currency OrderNum Price  
USD   123   1000; 2000  
USD   456   3000  
USD   789   4000  
USD   753   5000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure from your description how Type should be used here, but to form a single price line you can use `String.Join`:

```
Price = String.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.Price))
```

And just in case you are running .Net version older than 4.0, make sure to convert second param to an array:

```
Price = String.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.Price).ToArray())
```

Comment: You nailed it bro. Thanks a lot. I will tagged your answer as answered. Waiting for few minutes